# How to set width of y-axis tick labels in ggplot2 in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to left align the plot panels in a vertical array of ggplot2 graphs in R. The maximum width of the y-axis tick labels varies from graph to graph, breaking this alignment, as shown in the sample code below.

I've tried various plot, panel, and axis.text margin options without success, and have not been able to find an option for controlling the width of the y-axis tick labels.

Guidance appreciated.

```
#install.packages(c("ggplot2", "gridExtra", "reshape2"), dependencies = TRUE)
require(ggplot2)
require(gridExtra)
require(reshape2)

v <- 1:5
data1 <- data.frame(x=v, y=v)
data2 <- data.frame(x=v, y=1000*v)
plot1 <- ggplot(data=melt(data1, id='x'), mapping=aes_string(x='x', y='value')) + geom_line()
plot2 <- ggplot(data=melt(data2, id='x'), mapping=aes_string(x='x', y='value')) + geom_line()
grid.arrange(plot1, plot2, ncol=1)
```

Comment: Could elaborate on what you are looking to do? Maybe illustrate your desired behavior somehow?

Comment: I seek to align the left edge of each plot frame, as shown in the solutions below provided by MLavoie and Didzis Elferts. Thanks for prepending the package instructions to my code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use function `plot_grid()` from library `cowplot` to align plots

```
# install.packages(c("ggplot2", "cowplot", "reshape2"), dependencies = TRUE)
library(cowplot)
plot_grid(plot1,plot2,ncol=1,align="v")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. This is exactly what I sought, and worked correctly when applied to both my test code (shown), and to my actual code (not shown).

Comment: This removes the default ggplot theme and axes grids, but alignment works correctly.

Answer (score 2):

would this something like that work for you:

```
data1$Data <- "data1"
data2$Data <- "data2"
data3 <- rbind(data1, data2)
ggplot(data=data3, aes(x=x, y=y)) + geom_line() + facet_grid(Data~., scales = "free_y")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, which might be a good solution in some cases. In my actual code, rather than in the sample I provided, each member of the vertical array of graphs is quite different, so this solution might not be ideal for my particular case.

Answer (score 0):

like this? (code below)

[image]

```
# install.packages(c("ggplot2", "gridExtra", "reshape2"), dependencies = TRUE)
require(ggplot2)
require(gridExtra)
require(reshape2)

v <- 1:5
data1 <- data.frame(x=v, y=v)
data2 <- data.frame(x=v, y=1000*v)
plot1 <- ggplot(data=melt(data1, id='x'), mapping=aes_string(x='x', y='value')) + geom_line() + scale_y_continuous(breaks=NULL)
plot2 <- ggplot(data=melt(data2, id='x'), mapping=aes_string(x='x', y='value')) + geom_line() + scale_y_continuous(breaks=c(1000,2000))
grid.arrange(plot1, plot2, ncol=1)
```

Comment: Not quite—I sought to align the left edges of the plot frame. However, thanks for illustrating.